# Need suggestion to move a big live file in linux

Tags: linux

Multiple scripts are running in my Linux server which are generating huge data and I realise that it will eat all my 500GB of storage size in next 2-5 days and scripts require 10 more days to finish the process means they need more space. So most likely I am going to have a space issue problem and I will have to restart the entire process again.
Process is like this -
`script1.sh` content is like below

```
"calling an api" > /tmp/output1.txt
```

script2.sh content is like below

```
"calling an api" > /tmp/output2.txt
```

Executed like this -

```
nohup ./script1.sh & ### this create file in  /tmp/output1.txt 
nohup ./script2.sh & ### this create file in  /tmp/output2.txt
```

My understand initially was, if I will follow below steps, it should work --
when scripts are running with nohup in background execute this command -

```
mv /tmp/output1.txt /tmp/output1.txt_bkp; touch /tmp/output1.txt
```

And then transfer this file `/tmp/output1.txt_bkp` to another server via ftp and remove it after that to get space on server and script will keep on writing in `/tmp/output1.txt` file.

But this assumption was wrong and script is keep on writing in `/tmp/output1.txt_bkp` file. I think script is writing based on inode number that is why it is keep on writing in old file.

Now the question is how to avoid space issue without killing/restart scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what you're trying to do is pull a file out from under a script that's actively writing into it. I'm not sure how `nohup` would let you do that.

May I suggest a different approach?

Why don't you move an x number of lines from your `/tmp/output[x].txt` to `/tmp/output[x].txt_bkp`? You can do so without much trouble while your script is running and dumping stuff into `/tmp/output[x].txt`. That way you can free up space by shrinking your `output[x]` files.

Try this as a test. Open 2 terminals (or use `screen`) to your Linux box. Make sure both are in the same directory. Run this command in one of your terminals:

```
for line in `seq 1 2000000`; do echo $line >> output1.txt; done
```

And then run this command in the other before the first one finishes:

```
head -1000 output1.txt > output1.txt_bkp && sed -i '1,+999d' output1.txt
```

Here is what's going to happen. The first command will start producing a file that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
...
2000000
```

The second command will chop off the first 1000 lines of `output1.txt` and put them into `output1.txt_bkp` and it will do so WHILE the file is being generated.

Afterwards, look inside `output1.txt` and `output1.txt_bkp`, you will see that the former looks like this:

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
...
2000000
```

While the latter will have the first 1000 lines. You can do the same exact thing with your logs.

**A word of caution:** Based on your description, your box is under a heavy load from all that dumping. This may negatively impact the process outlined above.

Comment: nohup is to just let the script run even if there is network failure in ssh connection.